# network issue in one docker compose with keycloak and tomcat container

Tags: docker-compose

Greeting,

I'm a beginner is learning web authentication, and would like to try with tomcat and keycloak in docker compose. I put them in one docker-compose.yml as follows:

```
version: '2'

services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        environment:
            POSTGRES_DATABASE: 'keycloak'
            POSTGRES_USER: 'keycloak'
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'keycloak'
            POSTGRES_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'test'
        volumes:
            - ./postgres:/mnt/shares/postgres
    keycloak:
        image: jboss/keycloak-postgres
        ports:
            - "800:8080"
        links:
            - postgres
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR: 'postgres'
            POSTGRES_DATABASE: 'keycloak'
            POSTGRES_USER: 'keycloak'
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'keycloak'
            KEYCLOAK_USER: 'admin'
            KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: 'admin'
            POSTGRES_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'test'
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        volumes:
            - ./keycloak:/mnt/shares/keycloak
    tomcat_keycloak:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "880:8080"
        volumes:
            - ./web:/mnt/shares/web
            - ./scratches:/mnt/shares/scratches
```

This can launch fine. Next I created the realm, client, and user in the keycloak, obtained a keycloak.json for tomcat as follows:

```
{
    "realm": "TestRealm",
    "auth-server-url": "http://192.168.208.130:800/auth",
    "ssl-required": "external",
    "resource": "test-client",
    "public-client": true,
    "use-resource-role-mappings": true
}
```

where 192.168.208.130 is my host ip address. Then I tried a static web link in my tomcat server. I could be redirected to the keycloak login page. But after entering user name and password, I got HTTP status 403. In the keycloak events I saw the logon was successful, and a session was established. I checked the tomcat output, and then found the following:

07-Apr-2017 17:37:04.240 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.tryConnect I/O exception (java.net.NoRouteToHostException) caught when connecting to {}->http://192.168.208.130:800: No route to host (Host unreachable)

Looks like from my tomcat container, I cannot do HTTP client connection to my keycloak server container via the URL in host ip address. I can ping the host ip from the tomcat container though.

Could you help me to find out what I'm missing in this configuration? Really appreciate.

Comment: Have you tried linking tomcat container with keycloak? In your compose file this seems not to happen, so i would claim that this is the issue.

Comment: Yes I tried that. By linking tomcat container with keycloak you meant adding keycloak under links within tomcat_keycloak, right? That seems redundant. Without that I can ping keycloak container from tomcat container.

Comment: That's exactly what I ment. Create a link to keycloak under tomcat_keycloak, as far as I understand pinging the container not necessarily mean that they can talk on the specified port. Another thing that you can try is to change your auth-server-url to http://keycloak:8080/auth, as both containers are on the same docker host there shouldn't be the need to use external IP for connecting